# Android ensure animation rendered before transition

Tags: android, android-activity, android-animation, android-transitions

Im transitioning between 2 activities using

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_left)
```

My second activity has a frame layout which it then adds a fragment to using

```
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, tag).commit()
```

The problem is that the second Activity with the fragments view isn't rendered until about halfway / end of the transition meaning it appears that I am transitioning to a blank screen.

Is there away to not start the transition until the second activity has finished rendering?

Also I need this to work on API levels < 21

Answer (score 0):

Ok I managed to get this working. I was starting the new activity with the following flags:

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
```

to stop the user going back to them. Instead I removed the flag and called

```
finish()
```

After

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_left);
```

I guess it is because I was starting a whole new task, meaning the startup takes a little longer